# getText.toString() changes symbols to Unicode

Tags: java, android, retrofit, tostring, symbols

I have a edittext field in my app where end user enters their email for logging in.

When I use getText.toString() to get the value of the field the @ symbol is converted automatically to %40 and breaks the passed values to the POST request.

I guess I am missing something simple to stop the auto converting.
I see the issue is with;

```
@Field(encoded = false, value = "username") String username
```

Comment: ok, should have changed the value "username" to "email" as the server requires to param passed as "email" .. began working correctly after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the server actually requires the field to be "email", worked correctly when I changed the Retro Fit as per below;

```
//changed value = "username" to value = "email"
@Field(encoded = false, value = "email") String username
```

Answer (score 0):

A post request parameters get encoded based on the content-type header. You should have your content-type set as "text/html" in order to prevent the encoding.

Alternatively, you can use below code to decode the value as well.

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(receivedStringValue, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: The issue is with Retro Fit I believe. I am using @Field(encoded = false, value = "username") String username but it is still being encoded.